# Android NDK exception handling

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

I'm trying to figure out the support for exception handling while writing NDK based libraries. From these links: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html and http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html, what I could understand is that C++ exception handling is added for NDK revisions > r5, only for enabled "gnustl" runtime. However, does NDK have support for C++ STL? If so, does it support STL exceptions handling as well? Any comments on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android NDK provides support of `GNU STL` library and C++ exceptions handling. To link against `GNU STL` and enable exceptions handling put these lines into your `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
```

Comment: If you use visual studio, you can do that by right clicking the project and setting "gunstl_static" in general -> STL type and remember to also set "enable C++ exceptions" ( -fexceptions) in C/C++ -> Code Generation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the exceptions that NDK supports are STL exceptions.

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify, it supports STL exception in addition to standard C++ exception, right?

Comment: @pree There is no such thing as an *"STL exception"*. Likewise, your made-up exception is not supported. The NDK r5 introduced support for C++ exceptions.